# Flatten 2D Array/"Table" of Data without Unpivot

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

This feels like it should be relatively straightforward had I access to a sensible programming language like Python or P′′, but the built in Excel functions aren't applicable as shall be explained, and I'm running against the edges of my knowledge.

## The Input Data:

An example of what the data looks like to illustrate what I'm working with:

[image: input data]

I have added some annotations in *italics*.

My first thought was "unpivot", but due to all the column headers being dynamically generated, I can't turn it into a table and consequently unpivot is disallowed.

I think a lot of the store data columns are redundant, so I will enquire with colleagues about getting rid of the excess, but this is what it looks like as of now.

## The Goal:

This data (the main red area in the above screenshot) needs "flattening" into 1 row per value, which is the format needed for input into a database by another team. An example of what the sheet currently has as an output is in this screenshot, with colours matching the first image:

[image: Example output]

That is, a row for every store, for every date. Or every value in that 2D array read left-to-right, top-to-bottom and written out vertically, including some of the store details and the headers as columns.

As you can see some of the column headers have different names, I will **most likely** just rename the discrepant headers in the source data.  Also there are several additional columns that I can generate based on other using formulae. Their order does not matter.

Annoyingly, new stores will sometimes open, so the sheet can get vertically taller, so a solution needs to be able to adjust to encapsulate a new store.

## My Thoughts So Far

Strictly speaking, thanks to the dynamic nature of most the data, the wanted output can iterate over the main data values and just populate a column of CC codes and dates as such:

| Code | Date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/23 | value 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |

...and then the other columns can be calculated based on that data as mentioned.

If it helps your solution I can rearrange the store data columns and header rows as needed.

Unfortunately I'm also limited to Excel 2016 until the company eventually upgrades - however I need this done before the next ice age so I can't use anything introduced in Excel 2019 or later. No spills, `LET()`, etc.

## Macro/Pseudocode

I am leaning toward a macro activated on a button click being the solution here, I've attempted to write my own but I don't have enough knowledge of VBA to do it properly. I have programming experience in other languages however so have outlined below pseudo-VBA-code for how I would imagine I would approach this.

I believe, rather than trying to use clever tricks for selecting a range of data, that the code should be as fool-proof, **explicit**, and simple to follow as possible, relying where it can on Excel's regular functions to determine variable values, e.g. the range to be worked with is much more easily defined - for non-programmers - through a few cell values than through modifying VBA. This would make it easier to maintain by people even less programming experienced than I am. E.g. the built in functions should automatically resize their selections when new data is added, so the code drawing on those calculated cells will adapt to changes automagically. This data can all be stored in named cells in some "Control Panel" sheet that can also house the buttons used to activate the macros.

```vb
Sub makeOutput()
  Dim srcSheet as Worksheet
  Dim ctrlSheet as Worksheet
  Dim outputSheet as Worksheet 'importantly the sheet already exists and probably already contains some data, more on this later. 
  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  Dim dataHeight As Long, dataWidth As Long 'size of the block of values (red in the screenshot)
  Dim dataStart ' top left cell of the data range
  Dim outputArr()
  Dim ccRange As Range 'The range containing the CC numbers 
Dim dateRange as Range 'Range of date values 

  Set srcSheet = Sheets("Daily Sales Forecast") 'I'll either make this an argument to the function or just copy-paste the whole subroutine for each sheet that follows this pattern and change the name here. 
  Set outputSheet = Sheets("Daily Sales Output") ' as above, could be an argument so I can recycle this subroutine
  Set ctrlSheet = Sheets("Control Panel")
  With ctrlSheet
    dataHeight = .Range("Data_Height").Value ' from named cell
    dataWidth = .Range("Data_Height").Value ' from named cell
    dataStart = .Cells(.Range("Start_Col").Value, .Range("Start_Row").Value)  ' from named cells that use =CELL("row",data:range) and =CELL("col", data:range) so if anything moves the data range, it'll automatically update these selectors. 
  End With
  
  ReDim Preserve outputArr(3,srcDataRange.Count) 'make the intermediary output array sized 3 wide (for CC, Date, Value columns), and the height of all the value cells.

  With srcSheet ' this is where I'm starting to struggle:
    Set srcDataRange = dataStart.Resize(dataHeight, dataWidth) ' does this work..? 
    Set ccRange = .Range(" EXPLICIT_RANGE_REFERENCE_HERE") ' the CC column is probably not going to move, so I'm ok hardcoding it. It's B4:B7 in the example screenshot
    Set
  End With

  ' Now we're entering "very unsure" territory:
 
  ' Lets construct our output array: 
  Dim counter As Integer ' Keeps track of which cell in the srcData we're at
  counter = 0
  For i = 1 To dataWidth  ' iter cols (x-axis, in my mind)
    For j = 1 To dataHeight ' iter rows (y-axis)
      counter = counter + 1
      ' first column of output can be the value:
      outputArr(counter, 1) = srcDataRange.Cells(i, j) ' not sure if i and j are the right way around...
      ' col 2 can be the CC code:
      outputArr(counter, 2) = ccRange.Cells(1, i) ' I don't know if indexes are relative to range origin or sheet origin, if the latter then `1` is incorrect here and would need padding out or calculated to be the column index of CC column. Could do that anyway and avoid needing to define "ccRange" at all, but we're being explicit/idiot-proof here so I prefer a variable. 
      ' col 3 can be the date:
      outputArr(counter, 3) = 
    Next
  Next
  
  ' This is where I have truly run out of steam, I now need to paste `outputArr` into `outputSheet`'s first 3 columns, starting from row 2, such that column headers don't get overwritten. I also need to not overwrite anything in the fourth column and beyond (D+) as I'll have put some more functions in these columns by hand. 
End Sub
```

Edit: As requested, the control panel that I envision accompanying my pseudocode (ranges based on example screenshot):

| Data_Width | Data_Height | Start_Col | Start_Row |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| =COLUMNS('Daily Sales Forecast'!G4:L8) | =ROWS('Daily Sales Forecast'!G4:L8)-1 | =CELL("col",'Daily Sales Forecast'!G4:L8) | =CELL("row",'Daily Sales Forecast'!G4:L8) |

The `-1` on the `Data_Height` cell is to offset the fact that the range `G4:L8` includes a blank row at the bottom, which allows automatic expansion of the range when a new row/store is inserted at the bottom of the dataset. (minimising the work busy finance people need to do in future). Doesn't matter if the range selection is a bit long or short for the `CELL` functions as we're just fetching the top-left cell.

If I can clarify anything else please do comment and thank you kindly for any help.

Comment: From where does the `wc` column originate?

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome Hi, that's just "Week commencing", I have a sheet to calculate/look that up based on the date elsewhere so it doesn't need worrying about :D

Comment: Do you understand what a 1D array is?

Comment: @FaneDuru yes, and the values (the main body of my data) would become 1D from the 2D they are here. Apologies if it's poorly phrased I had been at this problem for several hours and fried my brain in the process

Comment: Interesting... If so, can you specify how many columns may a 1D array have?

Comment: @FaneDuru is this your idea of a productive conversation

Comment: I am just curious about your way of understanding this concept... 1D means an array with **only one dimension**. Being involved rows and columns, what you require is a 2D array and after so much effort of describing the problem it's  a pity to remain with a wrong concept. Even if it has a single row and more columns, or a single column and more rows, it is still **a 2D array**...

Comment: My understanding is that the heart of my data needs flattening, perhaps that would be a better term/ Unless you have an actual suggestion. I'm fully aware that the result is 2D but fundamentally a solution must be based around flattening a 2D array of values into a 1D array of values, carrying what one could consider metadata for those values?

Comment: Flattening a 2D is similar with transforming it in 1D, but you don't need that. Your requirement is a kind of transposing (some rows) to columns. But I am afraid that the discussion is useless, indeed. Have a nice day! Anyhow, you received (many hours before) an answer doing what you required and you did not send any feedback to the one consuming his time to help. I can post another answer (more compact) but this one looks OK. It would be good to try understanding it, I think. Is it anything wrong with the received answer?

Comment: I'm testing out the answer now but struggling to make it work for my data, as I'm getting an unhelpful error. (Are there not better development environments for these macros? the built in editor is awful) I'm going to update the question with screenshots from the actual document now that I have access to it again, in case there's anything adding complication.

Comment: It is also good to learn that **no need to struggle** if you clearly explain what you (really) have against what you need. Using dummy data, but the structure **must be exactly the one you have/need**, if your skills in VBA are not so high...

Comment: The structure I proposed is near identical, but alas only from memory at the time I first wrote the question. Regardless the structure *could change slightly* for reasons beyond my control (see: I work with other people with their own wants and desires) so a solution needs to handle some occasional tweaking, which to @taller_ExcelHome 's credit it looks like their solution *should* deal with such tweaks.

Comment: A structure CLEAR definition may include variable parameters. The idea is that you must clearly explain this aspect. You will design the code in a different way, if variable data have to be taken in consideration, against the case involving fixed parameters. If you talked only about variation of the rows to be transposed, everything in terms of variable part adaptation is referring to the fixed one. His idea was good, but not knowing that the fixed part will not be **so fixed, anymore** he neglected to report the variable part variation to something variable, too. I hope you learned something.

Comment: I am pretty sure I said in my question that the number of "row headers" would be variable so I'm not entirely sure where you're getting the idea from that it would be fixed in that axis? Their answer literally tries to account for a varying length of initial columns... It even accommodates varying header rows despite me not even requiring that!

Comment: To the above - I genuinely rewrote the question about 17 times before posting it to try and make it more digestible, if there's something missing chances are it got obliterated in a rewrite. I've tried to again make that clearer

Comment: I am afraid that we do not speak the same language. And I am not referring to English. You waste your effort in explaining what was not required and viceversa, feeling offended by simple remarks able to make you better understand how to proceed. I started preparing an answer but I will abandon that. I can (also) waste my time in different ways. I wish you success! I was hopping that you learned something from our discussion. I am tempted to think that not so much, but nobody dies from such an issue...

Comment: Your approach to explaining your issues with my question initially came across as rude though I realise that is probably not your intention - I understand that I missed some useful information and much information was buried in too-long paragraphs. I am happy to continue clarifications. Were I not current in the office I'd re-write the entire question again but I'm stuck scribbling these comments and minor edits between other work, so I also apologise for not being more proactive. It was difficult to decide what needed explaining and what didn't at the time

Comment: It is not good to have a very bushy question! It is necessary to be concise and clear. Place pictures showing the existing situation and the desired one. Then **try putting in our skin** and ask ask yourself what would we need in order to solve your problem. Generally, it should be enough. For instance, in the new picture, there are two last rows (73 and 74). Should we understand that determining the last row (he one containing "Sales less C&C"), the last row of the range to be processed would be obtained by subtracting two rows? I mean, to automatically determine the range to be processed...

Comment: "Bushy question" made me laugh, haha! Ok, when I get home I'm starting over the question and re-writing the question from scratch, hopefully far more sensibly and clearly. I have until month end to fix this, so I don't know why I've rushed so much. I think I just wanted to go to bed... I'll crack open the art skills and  try to draw more clearly what I'm expecting to happen, and add some pseudocode I've worked on. I feel like I'm 50% of the way with my own VBA macro but I lack the knowledge to finish it off so I'll include that to demonstrate my thinking too. See you again this evening!

Comment: I think it is good to wait for @taller_ExcelHome reaction to your comment. He can solve it very rapid, I think. In such a case, it would be good to learn about writing a good question, but generally. You may save same time if you wait a little... :) If what you said is not completely clear for him, he will ask for clarifications. A last pice of advice would be to check this page as frequent as possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim idx As Long, k As Long
    Dim arrData, arrRes(), newCol
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
    Const FIXED_COL_COUNT = 4 ' First 4 cols are fixed
    Const COL_COUNT = 8 ' 8 columns in output table
    Const HEADER_ROW = 3 ' Header row# in source table
    ' Extra new column name
    newCol = Array("Date", "wc", "WK No", "Value")
    Set srcSht = Sheets("Sheet2") ' source sheet, update as needed    
    With srcSht
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ' load data
        arrData = .Range("A1", .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
    End With
    idx = 1
    ReDim Preserve arrRes(1 To COL_COUNT, 1 To idx)
    ' Output table header
    For k = 1 To COL_COUNT
        If k > FIXED_COL_COUNT Then
            arrRes(k, idx) = newCol(k - FIXED_COL_COUNT - 1)
        Else
            arrRes(k, idx) = arrData(HEADER_ROW, k)
        End If
    Next
    ' Extract data
    For i = HEADER_ROW + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        For j = FIXED_COL_COUNT + 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
            idx = idx + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrRes(1 To COL_COUNT, 1 To idx)
            For k = 1 To FIXED_COL_COUNT
                arrRes(k, idx) = arrData(i, k)
            Next
            arrRes(FIXED_COL_COUNT + 1, idx) = arrData(2, j)
            arrRes(FIXED_COL_COUNT + 3, idx) = arrData(1, j)
            arrRes(FIXED_COL_COUNT + 4, idx) = arrData(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    ' Add new sheet to store output
    Sheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrRes, 2), UBound(arrRes)).Value = Application.Transpose(arrRes)
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

---

Update:

> Requirement is from revised OP and comments.

***Note***: The formula of `Data_Width` should be `=COLUMNS('Daily Sales Forecast'!G4:L8)` (Pls update the OP if I were right).

The code closely adheres to the flow of your pseudocode whenever feasible.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub makeOutput()
    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ctrlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim outputSheet As Worksheet 'importantly the sheet already exists and probably already contains some data, more on this later.
    Dim c As Long, r As Long
    Dim startRow As Long, startCol As Long
    Dim dataHeight As Long, dataWidth As Long 'size of the block of values (red in the screenshot)
    Dim dataStart As Range ' top left cell of the data range
    Dim outputArr()
    Dim ccRange As Range 'The range containing the CC numbers
    Dim dateRange As Range 'Range of date values
    Dim srcDataRange As Range
    
    Set srcSheet = Sheets("Daily Sales Forecast") 'c'll either make this an argument to the function or just copy-paste the whole subroutine for each sheet that follows this pattern and change the name here.
    Set outputSheet = Sheets("Daily Sales Output") ' as above, could be an argument so c can recycle this subroutine
    Set ctrlSheet = Sheets("Control Panel")
    
    With ctrlSheet
        dataHeight = .Range("Data_Height").Value ' from named cell
        dataWidth = .Range("Data_Width").Value ' from named cell
        startRow = .Range("Start_Row").Value
        startCol = .Range("Start_Col").Value
        Set dataStart = srcSheet.Cells(startRow, startCol) ' get the top-left cell ref
    End With

    With srcSheet
        Set srcDataRange = dataStart.Resize(dataHeight, dataWidth) ' does this work..?
        Set ccRange = .Cells(startRow, "B").Resize(dataHeight, 1) ' hardcode is not recommanded
    End With
    
    ReDim outputArr(1 To srcDataRange.Cells.Count, 1 To 3) 'make the intermediary output array sized 3 wide (for CC, Date, Value columns), and the height of all the value cells.
    
    ' Lets construct our output array:
    Dim counter As Long ' Keeps track of which cell in the srcData we're at
    counter = 0
    For r = 1 To dataHeight ' iter rows (y-axis)
        For c = 1 To dataWidth  ' iter cols (x-axis, in my mind)
            counter = counter + 1
            ' first column of output can be the value:
            outputArr(counter, 1) = srcDataRange.Cells(r, c)   ' not sure if c and r are the right way around...
            ' col 2 can be the CC code:
            outputArr(counter, 2) = ccRange.Cells(r)
            ' col 3 can be the date:
            outputArr(counter, 3) = srcSheet.Cells(2, startCol - 1 + c)
        Next
    Next
    ' paste `outputArr` into `outputSheet`'s first 3 columns, starting from row 2
    With outputSheet
        .Range("A2").Resize(counter, 3).Value = outputArr
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much for putting the time into this; I'm about to update the question with real screenshots as this code produced an error (Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range) when I tried to apply it. My FIXED_COL_COUNT is 6 so I entered this and entered the actual sheet name. Take a look at the new image. I suspect the totals row might be causing a problem, very sorry to have forgotten it before. I could probably have a new "control" sheet with cells for the height and width of the data? I imagine being able to pull those values from a fixed place would be easier?

Comment: Adding to the above, I can have a "control panel" sheet with information like "data width" and "data height" just using `COLUMNS()` and `ROWS()` and pick out where the top-left of the data is, using `COLUMN` and `ROW` from some template page, so it should be easier (I imagine) to figure out the range to be iterated over. From there the header rows could be separately picked from with `i`/`j`? Just trying to think how to make Excel do more of the work.

Comment: Are all 6 fixed columns in the expected output table? If so, pls update the 2nd screenshot. I don't think an extra control table is necessary.

Comment: The ones that are in the output are just "CC", I can generate all the other non-"value" columns based on "CC" and the "Date", if some code can generate a 3-column table of CC, Date, value, I can complete the rest. I'm currently rewriting my question more clearly with some illustrations of what I want, including exactly what is wanted in the output table. Give me a while and I'll send another reply here to let you know when it's updated, please don't waste your time before I've made the update!

Comment: Good to know. If any columns are already present in the source table, transferring them to the output using VBA is a straightforward process. It will save your time that would otherwise be spent populating the output table with formulas after running the code.

Comment: I'm sort of stuck with balancing it so that the source table is actually readable and including enough information to make it as smooth a process as possible to do VBA magic to rearrange it all. My thought was that rather than using magic functions to stretch the selection out to all the data, just be more explicit about the range values at play, hence a hidden sheet to let excel do the work. I come from Python Zen world, where explicit is best. I'm also trying to make this tamper-proof while letting people enter data, so code needs to be very robust. I can't guarantee much if its hardcoded :/

Comment: Honestly don't worry too much about the populating with functions, the size of the output won't change often, few times a year maybe, so if the data can be reliably dropped into the same 3 columns of a named sheet it's trivial to extend the "manual" columns to conform to the same size. I might enquire tomorrow with IT as to what the process looks like, e.g. can I get away with rearranging the columns to put CC,Date,value in A,B,C. I'll just update with new graphics and hopefully get back to you tomorrow with yet more refined goals. our entire network fell over today so I didn't have much time

Comment: I've made my edits, hopefully you can see what I'm going for! I do appreciate the use of clever functions to select data etc. but I do think its best to have simpler, longer, explicit code and some inputs defined in cells so non-programmers can have an easier time understanding what's going on and have it be harder to break. People with less free time than the nerdy apprentice will have to use and update this :(

Comment: Please provide a sample of "Control Panel" which is based on the 1st screenshot and share it as Markdown table in OP. It is convenient for me to copy and reproduce env. for testing.

Comment: Pls double check the formula of Data_Width. If I were right, it should be `=COLUMNS('Daily Sales Forecast'!G4:L8)`.

Comment: absolutely right, no idea where I got 2 from! New answer looks beautiful, really smart use of the height data to not hardcode the range, love that. let me try it out

Comment: It only went and worked - amazing, answer accepted, I only wish I could award you more rep. In my real document I've added a check/correction into the cell that calculates the the width of the data so it will deal with leap years (e.g. -1 if not a leap year 365/366)